# Sager NP6165 (Realtek) Wireless Not Working

Tags: 12.04, wireless

Hello I'm having issues with my new laptop (Sager NP6165) getting wireless.

I've been searching for a solution, to no avail.

My Network Card,

Integrated 802.11 b/g/n wireless LAN half mini card module + Bluetooth

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7900000-f7903fff

lspci
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen http://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the same realtek driver posted on this thread:

[Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized)

Just follow the steps on the first answer.