# Can't access wireless network in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers

I've just installed ubuntu on a laptop that came with Windows 7 pre-installed. In Windows 7 I was able to connect to the same wireless network that the other computers in my house are connected to but I can't do so in Ubuntu.

When I open Network through System Settings I don't have a wireless option, the only two options I have are Wired and Network Proxy.

I'm trying wireless troubleshooting on help.ubuntu and apparently the driver is unclaimed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should start with stating the model of your laptop and the wireless card you are using.

Comment: You can use the `lspci` command from the Terminal (Ctlr+Alt+T) and give us the output of the program (so that we can know the hardware of your laptop).

Answer (score 0):

At first go to Settings - Additional Drivers and try to install wireless driver.

If it's already installed and you still don't have wireless option try installing Wicd network manager. Install it by Ubuntu Software Center or by terminal

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-daemon
```

Then start it. Under Applications-Internet, or by terminal just type `wicd.`

Check now if you can see and connect to any wireless network.

**In case of problems while installing (just installed it via Ubuntu Software Center, so no problems there)..
http://wicd.sourceforge.net/moinmoin/Wicd%20on%20Ubuntu

Comment: When I open Additional Drivers it gives me a message saying 'Downloading package indexes failed, please check your network status. Most drivers will not be available.'

Comment: In terminal type < sudo apt-get update >

and then try Additional drivers..

Comment: I can't use Ubuntu Software Centre because without the wireless network I have no internet connection.

Comment: You have to connect temporary by cable to download and configure wireless conection..

Comment: I tried < sudo apt-get update > but all of the updates failed.

Comment: Check if you are connected to internet at all.. open browser and try surfing the web. If you are then try < sudo apt-get update > and then Additional drivers...

Comment: Right, I've connected to the internet via cable. I tried < sudo apt-get update > but when I go on additional drivers it says there are no proprietary drivers in use on the system. How do I install the driver?

Comment: Also, I downloaded Wicd network manager but it says that no wireless networks were found.

Comment: I've found a page on help.ubuntu that explains how to install the wireless driver but I don't know how to obtain the wireless driver. Where do I get it from?

Comment: Check if your wireless is turned on on laptop (wifi button), also check these and some other posts for resolving your issue.

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/troubleshooting-wireless.html

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless.html

Comment: I've managed to fix the problem using this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help, I'd have never fixed it otherwise

Comment: No problem, glad that I could help.