# I keep losing connectivity with an RTL8723E wireless card (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet-connection, realtek

I have a realtek RTL8723E network card. It connects for about 3 minutes, but then suddenly disconnects and then reconnects after about a minute. This really hinders my ability to use Ubuntu, as I want to learn to use it but without the internet it is basically pointless.

I know it's the correct driver, but maybe there is some package that magically fixes problems like this. A man can dream. Also, it isn't the router settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to install both drivers from this page even if you don't need/have bluetooth. That worked for me. Here you have the link:

[Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized)