# Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT driver not compiling on Quetzal

Tags: wireless, 12.10, realtek

Hello, I followed the instructions on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/165002/814) answer but at the `make` command I got this:

```
$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o
/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: error: ‘IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012$ sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o
/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: error: ‘IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ubuntu/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please help me solve this, thank you.

*Added by Oxwivi, also facing the same issue:*

> I followed the instructions as well, and they worked perfectly on Precise, without a single error. I've edited the question and added Quetzal to question and tags in addition to improving the question's format.
>
> Thank you for understanding.

Comment: By the way, you need at least 10 reputation points to comment. That is why you were unable to comment on the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem after upgrading to 12.10. I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/154935/814) from the original question, and it worked:

> Commenting out/removing the `IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER` (line 320 in `base.c`) [...]

:-)

Comment: That does not work for me.  I am getting a long stack trace and this message "rtlwifi-0:rtl_pci_probe():<0-0> Can't register mac80211 hw.".

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out `IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER` didn't work for me. I still had the same issue when trying to compile the driver (Error2 as mentioned in the question).

What finally did work very well, was using the latest stable Linux Kernel (I use 3.8.2, today 3.8.3 was published) from https://www.kernel.org/ as mentioned here: http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/wireless/477285-rtl8723ae-realtek-wirless-driver-hell-3.html#post2494079. The Driver for RTL8723ae is included in the Linux Kernel starting with Version 3.8.0.

There is no Ubuntu repository for that, thus you will have to compile (but don't skip configuring...) the kernel. `make oldconfig` should usually work fine (it reads the old kernel config file and asks for new symbols). See the Kernel Readme File for more details. Be aware of the fact that compiling the complete kernel may be time-consuming (ca. 1.5h on my Intel i3 Dualcore @ 2.1 GHz Laptop).

The Wireless Adapter works quite fine after rebooting, except some minor disconnections  due to a bad connection quality (but faster reconnections than using the dropbox driver with Ubuntu 12.4).