# Ubuntu 12.04 and realtek rtl8723ae some networks work, some not

Tags: 12.04, networking, realtek

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and MSI MS-16GC with Realtek 8723ae and here is my problem. It works with some networks every time (eg. my home network) but it worked with eq. network form my phone (HotSpot) and network on my university but now doesn't. I've tried to do the thing from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized) but I have this

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-35-generic/build M=/home/korek 
/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic'
CC [M]  /home/korek/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o
In file included from /home/korek
/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:39:0:
/home/korek/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/pci.h:245:15:   
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl_pci_probe’
/home/korek/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In   
function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/korek/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6:   
error: ‘IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/korek/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6:  
note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears   in
/home/korek/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In   
function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/korek/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:870:25:   
error: ‘RX_FLAG_MACTIME_MPDU’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/korek/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In  
function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/korek/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:1432:16:  
error: ‘struct <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘sta’
make[2]: *** [/home/korek/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 
/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/korek 
/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What I have to do to get it working every time?

Answer (score 0):

Update your version of the software.  Try version
rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012
(Note the last part is the date, which is later than yours).
Even later versions may exist, but the above should work.

---

Here's a similar problem with suggested solution:
[Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT driver not compiling on Quetzal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203078/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-driver-not-compiling-on-quetzal)

Comment: It still the same. Even Errors are the same