# Problem with Realtek 8723

Tags: realtek

after installing 12.10, I tried to install the drivers for my wireless chipset, Realtek 8723. After I downloaded and extracted the files, I tried to compile, but I received an error message:

```
daniel@ubuntu:~/Descargas/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/daniel/Descargas/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 modules
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic»
  CC [M]  /home/daniel/Descargas/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o
/home/daniel/Descargas/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: En la función ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/daniel/Descargas/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: error: ‘IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER’ no se declaró aquí (primer uso en esta función)
/home/daniel/Descargas/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: nota: cada identificador sin declarar se reporta sólo una vez para cada función en el que aparece
make[2]: *** [/home/daniel/Descargas/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/daniel/Descargas/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic»
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. See this question for [debugging hardware](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) problems and edit your question by adding some more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in: https://askubuntu.com/a/154935/814

In short, the answer is:
Commenting out/removing the IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER (line 320 in base.c)