# Wired connection doesn't work in Quantal - Toshiba c850

Tags: drivers, internet-connection, atheros, toshiba

It has `Realtek Wireless RTL8723AE` card and `Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet` [1969:1090]

I was able to get the wireless working from [Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized)
but cannot get the wired connection to work

How can I solve this? Will the future releases of Ubuntu support these cards?

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
   wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.5/compat-wireless-3.5.1-1-snpc.tar.bz2
   tar -xf compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snpc.tar.bz2
   cd compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snpc
   ./scripts/driver-select alx
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo modprobe alx
```

Your ethernet should now be working.

When a new kernel version is installed by Update Manager, recompile:

```
    cd compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snpc
    ./scripts/driver-select restore
    ./scripts/driver-select alx
    make clean
    make
    sudo make install
    sudo modprobe alx
```

Answer (score 0):

The alx module has been added to the kernel updates, so anyone with wireless working can run:

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and reboot, selecting the new kernel, and ethernet should work.