# Failure of LAN Driver on Ubuntu 12.10 installed on Toshiba Satelite C850-P5010

Tags: 12.10, networking, drivers, lan, toshiba-satellite

I bought a new laptop Toshiba Satelite C850-P5010.After installing Ubuntu 12.10,failed to connect to Internet using an external modem.

I connected the modem (beetel 110TC1) to the LAN port the PC led indicator just went off. (no connectivity problem on Windows 7).The network icon on the top panal shows no network connection.

`sysinfo` displays the Network controller as:

```
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.Device8723 and Subsystem: 'Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.Device 0723
```

Ethernet controller:

```
Atheros Communications Device 1090(rev 10) and Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff1e
```

When I ran `lspci` in a terminal the result displayed was:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)  
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8723
```

I tried the solution given for " Installing Driver for AR8161 on an offline machine", but failed. How can I install Driver for AR8162 on my LAP?

Comment: Can anyboy help me?

Comment: How can I install Driver for AR8162 on my LAP ?

Comment: Have you tried using the unofficial drivers as explained [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/165002/21035) ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.buzzard.me.uk/toshiba/download.html by using another computer and download Thoshiba linux Utilities version 2.0.1 source. Then copy the driver into desktop & extract. Double click on `install.sh` file or run in terminal. Restart & connect net or try attach a usb modem (Huweai E303 D  / E1762- with idea 3g-INDIA- working) to connect net. Then update the kernel.