# Wireless Lan driver for Toshiba Satellite C850-A823 PSKCCV-02300XAR

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have Toshiba Satellite C850-A823 PSKCCV-02300XAR Laptop, i had installed Ubuntu 12.10 as dual boot (windows 7 already working), after the installation i had noticed that wireless driver not installed in ubuntu 12.10, from windows device manager i got details of wireless lan driver as follows

"Realtek RTL8723AE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC"

i dont have LAN cable connection, kindly help me how to get wireless driver and install in ubuntu 12.10

hoping for your kind support

shiyas

Answer (score 1):

Without an internet connection, you will need to download several packages on another computer and transfer them on a USB key or similar. Please go here and download the following: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

build-essential, libc6-dev, gcc, g++, make, dpkg-dev,
linux-headers-generic and linux-headers matching your running kernel.

Find out your running kernel with:

```
uname -r
```

For example, if you get 3.5.0-19-generic, then you will need to download and install linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic. When you have all these packages downloaded, move them to the desktop of the Ubuntu machine and install them with:

```
sudo dpkg -i Desktop/*.deb
```

The wildcard * means install *all* the .deb files. Be sure to download 32- or 64-bit as appropriate. At the download site, 32-bit are called i386 and 64-bit are amd64.

Now get the driver package here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57056576/DRIVERS/REALTEK/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012.tar.gz

Transfer it to your desktop, too. Right-click the tar.gz and select Extract Here. Back in the terminal, do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8723e
```

Let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: In [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/165002/88802) it is reported that you need another version for the 3.5 kernel.

Comment: Or use the Ubuntu 13.04, that comes with working 8723 drivers (and the alx ethernet driver too).