# How to reenable networking (wireless still not working)?

Tags: 12.04, networking, laptop, asus

I installed Kubuntu 12.04 few days ago on my new ASUS laptop. Right after the installation wired connection was not detected, but wireless worked just fine. So, I was able to get the latest updates, and after that both wired and wireless worked ok.

Yesterday I just wanted to see what happens if I boot in a previous version of Linux (I have that option at boot), and it booted, but network wasn't worked at all, neither wireless nor wired.

The problem is now network isn't working even if I boot normally, the lastest version.
I'm a newbie in Linux / Ubuntu, so I don't know what specific information should I provide more and how I find it, but I'll try to do it if someone guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue i have Toshiba satellite c850 -a989, this page really help me

[Wireless Lan driver for Toshiba Satellite C850-A823 PSKCCV-02300XAR](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224203/wireless-lan-driver-for-toshiba-satellite-c850-a823-pskccv-02300xar)

but what you should do is :

1. `lspci -l`  (command to list all devices on your pc).
2. see what is the type of your both wireless ans LAN driver type. go and download your correspond driver (in my case realtek) and follow the rest of commands

make sure you have packages mentioned in link i gave you. and follow the instruction for set it up

i wish this help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
When i typed lspci -l i got an error:

asusk@asusk-X75VD:~$ lspci -l
lspci: invalid option -- 'l'
Usage: lspci [<switches>]

then i tiped lspci without parameters, and i got this:

asusk@asusk-X75VD:~$ lspci

...
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)

Comment: As for the second part - downloading and installing drivers, i dont really think i have to do that, as it used to work just fine before yesterday. is it possible that simple booting in previous version of linux did delete those drivers?
my feeling is they should be steel there, but somehow get deactivated, and i don't know how to reactivate them.
i really prefer to try something easier (if there is any) befor going to remove/install drivers, because, as i said, i'm a newbie at linux.

Comment: thank you Jai even me i will use your answer, i have also a problem in toshiba c-850 i will also try to reinstall this packages

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is reconfigure the Latest Kernel image. [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29) work in our PC's to maintain the proper functionality of hardware with OS.

Find out the what is the latest kernel Image.

To do that the best way is installing synaptic package manager.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

then type as `synaptic` as in unity dash and open it. Then type as `linux` in the search box and find the latest one and right click it . Then choose reinstall.

look at the image [image]

Comment: Thank you, Jai! after reinstalling the package i was able to check "Enable networking" option (it wasn't there before), then restarted, and now wired connection works well. However, i'm not sure wireless is working; there is no wireless in range, so, i started tethering on my android phone, but i cannot see it on my laptop.

Comment: I am up to this only.

Comment: well, i'm home now, and i can confirm my wireless is **not** working :(. any more ideas?