# I am trying to build a Realtek 8723e module for my wireless but I am getting errors

Tags: kernel, make, modules

Following the instruction found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized) I have attempted to build this driver.

Some information about my laptop computer:

Toshiba Satellite S855-S5254

8 GB RAM

Intel i7-3610QM CPU 2.30 GHz

Ethernet - Atheros AR8161/8165 PCI-E Gigabyte ethernet controller

Wireless - Realtek RTL8723AE Wireless LAN 802,11n PCI-E NIC

64 Bit windows 7 OS installed

64 Bit Ubuntu Desktop 12.10 installed

A quick note, I have been using a USB wireless NIC to download files as necessary and then I remove it when it is not needed.

What I am getting is as follows:
 I first get the following using this syntax: 
 sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`

Which results in the following:

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
build-essential is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic is already the newest version.
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 220 not upgraded.

This was the second time I had executed the above syntax because I was not sure it had completed correctly.

Not sure as to if things were going correctly I then went to retrieve the driver tarball an extract it using the following:

wget -O- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57056576/DRIVERS/REALTEK/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012.tar.gz | tar -xz

I do believe all went well with this for all the files are there as listed in the archive listing,
I then excute the make command with the following results:

cd realtek
make

make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/slalonde/realtek modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/slalonde/realtek/base.o
make[1]: Leaving directory`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic'

And then I do the make install with the following results:

make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/slalonde/realtek modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/slalonde/realtek/base.o
make[1]: Leaving directory`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic'

I the check to see if the driver is there using the following:

sudo modprobe rtl8723e

FATAL: Module rtl8723e not found

So as you can see I am not having much success.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact `quad core i7 Toshiba laptop Satellite S855-S5254` with `Ethernet - Atheros AR8161/8165 PCI-E Gigabyte` ethernet controller and `Wireless - Realtek RTL8723AE Wireless LAN 802,11n PCI-E NIC`.

I first installed Ubuntu 12.10 on March 1st. The basic install did not recognize either my Ethernet OR Wireless card. I was able to get the Ethernet going by following http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2114293 (praseodym's contribution). Once this got going, I was able to use `apt-get` to update. Following which I got the wireless going by following instructions on [Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized) (user239558's contribution for the 3.5 linux kernel).

I think the issue is that you are using the driver build for the earlier kernel.