# no wifi on zoostorm laptop

Tags: wireless, 12.10

I have installed ubuntu 12.10 on a new Zoostorm Laptop, Intel Pentium DC B980 2.4GHz, 8GB RAM, 500GB HDD, 15.6\" HD LED. Ubuntu works a treat but the wifi will not work. Has anyone had a similar problem and knows how to fix it?
thanks

Comment: We need some more details, like what kind of card, but generally the problem is that there is no driver installed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please start troubleshooting here: [My WiFi adapter is not working at all. Where to start troubleshooting?](http://askubuntu.com/q/235279/88802)

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same laptop and the answer by izx from this thread did the job for me on Lubuntu 12.10:

[Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized)

I also fallowed user239558 suggestions and downloaded newest driver from here: 
www.liteon.com/UserFiles/driver/Module/Network/WLAN/RTL/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012.tar.gz