# Network card rtl8723e not accepted anymore in ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, wireless, internet, realtek

A time ago I bought a new laptop but I had a lot of problems with it.

First there was the problem with ubuntu who hadn't a driver for the network card. After a long search I found the solution here: [Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized). The solution with the dropbox link worked, but not for long.

Not long after that I had problems with the card in windows AND ubuntu (and I still have them sometimes). Sometimes the card just does not work. I have looked for a solution and let people from the IT-service in our school look but nobody of us could find a solution.

After that, I upgraded the kernel of ubuntu, which has the next problem because the driver only supported until kernel 3.3. But in the same article that I've mentioned before, someone gave a second link for kernel 3.5. But from that time, everytime I restart my computer the driver isn't working automatically. I had to enable it as an LKM with modprobe.

It worked for a while, but suddenly it stopped working. It doesn't work anymore to use modprobe to enable it and I've tried restarting, reinstalling the drivers, ... I installed almost everythink I could think of and what I could find on the internet.

Do anyone have a solution for this? It's so irritating... Thanks!

EDIT: Now working again (for a time...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I#ve had similar problems. 
I usually rebuilt the drivers from the Realtek file "rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012" when updating to a new kernel manually, using the commands:

```
sudo su 
make clean 
make 
sudo make install 
sudo modprobe rtl8723e
```

With Kernel 3.2.0-38 this didn't work anymore. I got error:

> Error inserting rtl8723e (/lib/modules/3.2.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723e/rtl8723e.ko): Invalid argument

In my case, uninstalling the "linux-backports-modules" (linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic) solved the poblem! :-)

Hope 4 you too!?

Greez from Germany,

Helmut

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Suddenly it worked again. I had found a newer version of the driver. The only problem was that it didn't start automatically anymore each time I rebooted. So I have solved it by loading the kernel module with /etc/modules. This helped me! Now it works most of the time!

Comment: Ok! Ir worked! I removed rtl8723 module from modprobe and disabled networking
 by doing sudo modprobe -r rtl8723e
and restarted. It just worked! :X