# Realtek rtl8723e wireless card will not connect

Tags: wireless, realtek

I'm having a problem with the Realtek RTL8723E like so many others, but in my case it simply refuses to connect. I am running Ubuntu 12.10 with the latest patches and kernel.

I referred to this excellent thread: [Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized) to try to install the Realtek Wireless card on a new laptop - the Zoostorm W251EU. I have tried everything in the thread but the network manager simply shows 'Wireless networks' greyed out and disconnected.

Oddly enough this worked before on kernel 3.5.0-25 ... but after a reboot yesterday stopped working and has not worked since.

1. Hardware switch - works, and it is on
2. `sudo lshw -C network` output

   ```
   *-network               
      description: Wireless interface
      product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
      vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
      logical name: wlan0
      version: 00
      serial: 20:68:9d:dc:fe:25
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723e driverversion=3.5.0-26-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
      resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff
   ```
3. `rfkill list` shows no hardware or software blocks
4. My blacklist is empty
5. Driver: `rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012` appears to make and install fine, but does not work any more. This worked previously with the 0-25 kernel (the problem appeared before the kernel upgrade to 0-26, I redid all the steps after installing kernel 0-26 in the hope it would start working again)
6. I'm running Windows 7 x64 inside VirtualBox, have tried to play with the network settings just in case there's some interference. No joy.

Answer (score 0):

I have one of these laptops and it is working for me (albeit slowly) on `3.5.0-27-generic`.

Did you try a

```
make clean
```

This will clear out all the old object files before making the driver with.

```
make
sudo make install
```

Failing this working try removing the directory and then untaring the driver and doing:

```
make
make install
```