# which ubuntu version to download for toshiba C850 laptop with rtl8723 ?

Tags: downloads

can you tell me which version of ubuntu to install on toshiba C850 laptop with wireless card rtl8723. I need the bootable cd/dvd with all packages installed like linux headers,build essentials,make etc.so that after installing compatible driver,it can connect to wify. not received any reply on my askubuntu qs also on my thread in ubuntu forum. Can anyone help?

Comment: check out this question, probably you'll have the same issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.04 (64bit for your UEFI machine) comes with a working alx driver for ethernet and rtl8723 driver for wireless.  You don't have to build anything to get networking anymore. I have no direct experience with the 32 bit distribution, but since they are build from the same sources, I'd expect that the drivers would be present there too.  You can download the 13.04 iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

Comment: Thanks ubfan1, my laptop is 32 bit so can you tell if ubuntu 13.04 32 bit also has inbuilt drivers ? Also could you please send me the url to dowoad this ? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks ubfan1, your suggestion helped and now Ubuntu 13.04 ,32 bit has made my both ethernet and wify work ! Without installing any packages or drivers. Your help was very valuable.Thank you.