# RTL82723AE-BT drivers for 12.04

Tags: wireless

I've recently installed 12.04 on a Zoostrom laptop. All is well apart from WiFi and the Webcam. I'm using a £12 dongle to solve the WiFi problem, but it would be nice to be able to dispense with this at some stage.

As I understand things - not very well - the problem is that the laptop is using a fairly new wireless chip, the RTL8273AE-BT, and the drivers for this chip are not included in the current 12.04 kernel. I'm currently using 3.5.0-36. There are a number of links advising on how to install the drivers, but I haven't managed to get these to work.

However, I also understand that the drivers are included in 3.8 and that this is used by 13.04. I don't want to switch to 13.04 - I like using LTS distributions - can anyone tell me whether:

1 the RTL8273AE-BT are in 3.8 and

2 whether 3.8 will eventually be used by 12.04 and, if so

3 when?

Comment: You have mistaken the chipset name in the question heading. It should be RTL8273AE-BT as in your details. The answers to your questions can be found [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Roger, you seem to have edited back the title. Are you sure it's rtl8273, and not rtl8723?

Answer (score 1):

The driver rtl8723ae *is* included in 3.8. You can install 3.8 from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.8-raring/

Be sure to download and install the version, either 32- or 64-bit, appropriate to your architecture. Also be sure to install linux-image-extra.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and compile the driver yourself for the 12.04 3.5 kernel:
wget -O- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57056576/DRIVERS/REALTEK/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012.tar.gz
I think even the live media will successfully run the compile, so your installed system should work too.