# Can't connect to my wireless network

Tags: wireless

I've just bought a new laptop and installed Ubuntu 12.04 in it.
My problem is that I can make a wired connection but not a wireless one.
The wireless network is working okay with other computers but not with the new one.
The new laptop can't detect it.
Can anyone help me?

```
On a terminal, typing lspci the output is
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8723
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

Inspecting the drivers installed the one for the Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8723 is not there. How do I install it?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  If your problem is solved, you should either accept an answer here or write your own answer to how you fixed this, and accept it.  Editing your title to say "Solved" does not actually mark your question as "answered" (aka "solved").

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been asked and answered already on ask ubuntu. Here is a link to the thread. [Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized). Hope that gives you the insight you need!

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: Could you please post the output of the following: `sudo lshw -C network -numeric`