# slow wifi connection on ubuntu 13.04 with rtl8723ae realtek wireless driver

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, realtek

so i have installed ubuntu four days ago on my toshiba SATELLITE-C855-2CF and everything is going well, but i noticed that my wifi connection is slow and when i did a speed test online i found that i have only 0.9 Mbps and when i did the speed test on windows i have 4Mbps so can someone tell me how can i fix this problem ? if don't find any solution for this problem i'll have to go back to windows and leave ubuntu.

```
$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SAGEM"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 4C:17:EB:3E:C4:0C   
      Bit Rate=18 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=34/70  Signal level=-76 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:6967   Missed beacon:0

$ lsmod | grep rtl
rtl8723ae              86459  0 
rtlwifi                79673  1 rtl8723ae
mac80211              606457  1 rtlwifi
cfg80211              510937  2 mac80211,rtlwifi


$ lspci | grep RTL
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)

$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 2c:d0:5a:3e:ee:bb
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723ae driverversion=3.8.0-27-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c2400000-c2403fff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 05
   serial: 70:54:d2:d6:d0:2b
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0004000-c0004fff memory:c0000000-c0003fff
```

Comment: i have the same issue with my wireless, same model. The wireless signal level goes up and down most of the time..

Comment: Is your kernel version 3.8.0-27 ? Type `uname -a` to know it. This version broke my wifi connection (95% of packets dropped) but not on all wifi routers.

Comment: @SteveK yes it is, $ uname -or => 
3.8.0-30-generic, my wifi is so slow it's killing me, i can't work like that, i need a solution

Comment: Maybe it's of any use but, on a machine with a wireless adapter doing wifi and bluetooth, enabling bluetooth broke the wifi connection. disabling it restored the connection. if you have bluetooth, this may be worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there are conflicts with the driver, so you can try installing the Official drivers for the WLAN NIC.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/165002/99886) should help you [but, a newer version of the driver can be downladed from [here](http://www.liteon.com/UserFiles/driver/Module/Network/WLAN/RTL/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012.tar.gz) Other steps remain the same.]. I'm pasting the answer below:

#### Realtek is making the official Linux driver available unofficially (via Dropbox)

Support for the RTL8273AE-BT has been added by Realtek in the 92-series driver, version 0006.0514.2012. For unknown reasons, neither the Windows nor Linux drivers are available on their website (yet). But Realtek tech support has been providing a Dropbox link with the source code/firmware tarball which numerous users have reported as working.

#### Where do I get it? Is it safe?

- The driver can be downloaded via [this Dropbox link.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57056576/DRIVERS/REALTEK/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012.tar.gz)
- I can confirm that this file is what it claims to be, with [this content listing](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1097947/), provided it has the following MD5 or SHA1 hashes: (which you can verify with `md5sum` or `sha1sum`)

  ```
  MD5: fd10e9a347c6447f649324d6bdab53de
  SHA1: 1ccd6ae73878d8bf65bd7c0384e333b121606230
  ```

#### How do I build and install the driver on Ubuntu?

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. You'll need to install these packages first to build the driver:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
   ```
3. Paste the below line to download and extract the driver archive in one single step:

   ```
   wget -O- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57056576/DRIVERS/REALTEK/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012.tar.gz | tar -xz
   ```
4. Change to the extracted driver's directory, build and install the driver:

   ```
   cd rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
5. Test the driver by loading it (this is a one-time step; after you reboot once, the driver should automatically load on every boot):

   ```
   sudo modprobe rtl8723e
   ```

Comment: It's a pleasure. :-)

Comment: This no longer works with the latest kernel.  Are Larry Finger's drivers at https://github.com/lwfinger the right ones to use now?

Answer (score 2):

You have a pretty marginal connection (quality 34/70), 6967 invalid misc packets, and your connection speed has dropped back to 18Mb/sec from the max of 54 for g networking.  Try improving your signal by moving your machine relative to the access point.  Another thing to check is the outside interference on your channel.  Use

> `sudo iwlist scan`

To see all the nearby access points and their channels/ strengths.  If you see many others on your channel (and really only 1 6 and 11 do not overlap, so nearby ones interfere too), try changing your channel.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced much better performance following the advice from this user:

https://zach-adams.com/2014/06/fixing-rtl8723ae-driver-ubuntu-linux/

In short, two stages:

1. Try installing the linux-firmware-nonfree drivers with this command:

   `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`
2. Try installing the WICD network manager. For instructions for your version of Ubuntu, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD