# RTL8723AE PCIe driver problem

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet, compiling, realtek

I have looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329932/slow-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-13-04-with-rtl8723ae-realtek-wireless-driver) but I get this error while compiling and am unable to load the module afterwards:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/build M=/home/owner/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013_patched modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/owner/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013_patched/base.o
/home/owner/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013_patched/base.c: In function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/owner/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013_patched/base.c:885:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
       rx_status.freq = hw->conf.channel->center_freq;
                                ^
/home/owner/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013_patched/base.c:886:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
       rx_status.band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                                ^
/home/owner/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013_patched/base.c: In function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/owner/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013_patched/base.c:1451:24: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
   info->band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                        ^
make[2]: *** [/home/owner/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013_patched/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/owner/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013_patched] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
owner@computer:~/Desktop/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013_patched$
```

This occurs with both the driver listed in the first link and the patched driver that I found.
I have also already tried disabling both the bluetooth and the adaptor.
Also I tried `iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30`.

Comment: What is it about the built-in driver that isn't working as expected? Installing an _older_ driver is seldom useful.

Comment: @chili555 the signal constantly fluctuates no matter how far or close I am to the router.  This is also true of the speed I get about 1/3 of the speed I get in windows then 1/2 a second later for about 30 seconds or more I get no data transfer and the cycle repeats. I just need a driver that WORKS... :(