# Connection issues with rtl8723ae wireless (maybe bad driver?)

Tags: wireless, networking

It constantly disconnects and the signal strength goes up and down. The problem is worse when another person connects and download movies. That should be a problem with either my pc or my router because my download speed should keep up with that, but I certainly need help. Thanks in advance.

P.D. I am a noob in Linux, beware.

Output of sudo lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Here is the error when "make":

make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-31-generic/build M=/home/alejandro/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/alejandro/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012/base.o
/home/alejandro/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012/base.c: In function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/alejandro/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012/base.c:872:25: error: ‘RX_FLAG_MACTIME_MPDU’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/alejandro/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012/base.c:872:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/alejandro/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012/base.c: In function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/alejandro/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012/base.c:1434:16: error: ‘struct <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘sta’
make[2]: *** [/home/alejandro/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/alejandro/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Have you seen this thread yet? Click on the " Dropbox" link
http://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized

Comment: Yep, but do is my problem the rtl8723aeBT drivers? Is not BT same as bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time helping you , because I don't have enough rep to leave comments. Yes, BT is bluetooth, but there are further instructions and links on that thread. I hoped your answer would be on there. Looks like alot of people have same issue.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I will try to build the driver listed there.

Comment: Why am I getting the 2 errors every time I "make"?

Comment: Post the errors and we'll try to suggest a fix.

Comment: Done pal, posted errors.