# How to make Realtek RTL8723A Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter work?

Tags: wireless, drivers

On Ubuntu 14.04, the WiFi adapter RTL8723A doesn't find any network.

Neither of these two workarounds worked for me:

- [Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized)
- [Thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2177333&page=2&s=8d7f7cadf4774b236a1776fb0a4cb03c)

I am using Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 13 (Model 20175) and as of now Bluetooth, Speakers and Mic are not working either.

Comment: There are a couple of different 8723 devices. We need to know additional details to help you. Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: rfkill list all also: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.