# can't scan any wifi connection on ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, openvpn

**Current Situation**:
With Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, wired connection is OK. While I enable Wifi, I coundn't find any conections. And I'm pretty sure the Wifi router is working since my cellphone's Wifi can connect to it.

**Methods I tried**:

1. The wireless adapter is connected since I can view it in `lspci`.
2. The device was not blocked with `rfkill`.
3. `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, the managed option under ifupdown is already 'true'.
4. network-manager restart won't work `sudo service network-manager restart`.

And finally, I run the wireless info script from this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos), hopes this has provided enough info:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23891726/

**Other Backgrounds**:
This issue happened after I turn down my Ubuntu without properly close a openvpn connection. And this same situation happened before. That last time I didn't mannually shut down openvpn, I had a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

After switching to Windows and boot back to Ubuntu, I can view WiFi connections. I suppose this openvpn issue was related but no evidence in that.

**edit 20170203**
The OS was installed, and wifi connections resumed. Today, I was installing WinXP via virtualbox from this same Ubuntu machine. During the process, the power came down. After rebooting back, This same situation reappeared. So I compiled the Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE driver as suggested, but still can't scan any wifi. Any further suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized)

Comment: @CelticWarrior: It appears the issue is related to a VPN running during suspend/resume. The network adapter driver seems to be fine.